# MySQL GROUP BY if condition

Tags: mysql

I want to return `movie_id` ONLY if all rows with same `movie_id` has `convert=2`.  If a row with same `movie_id` has `convert=0` then don't return `movie_id`.

Example:

This should return nothing because all three rows have the same movie_id but convert=0 on the last row

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| id | movie_id |    lang    | email_sent | user_request | convert |
+----+----------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  |    1     |   german   |     0      |      1       |    2    |
| 2  |    1     |   french   |     0      |      1       |    2    |
| 3  |    1     |   english  |     0      |      1       |    0    |
+----+----------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
```

This should return `movie_id` because all three rows have the same movie_id and convert=2 for all rows

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| id | movie_id |    lang    | email_sent | user_request | convert |
+----+----------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  |    1     |   german   |     0      |      1       |    2    |
| 2  |    1     |   french   |     0      |      1       |    2    |
| 3  |    1     |   english  |     0      |      1       |    2    |
+----+----------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Here is my query but isn't working when i try with second sample data, still returns `movie_id`

```
SELECT movie_id
from movie_subtitles
WHERE email_sent=0 AND user_request=1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN `convert`=2 THEN movie_id END
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a HAVING clause like this:

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movie_subtitles
WHERE email_sent=0 AND user_request=1
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING SUM(Convert <> 2) = 0
```